# Linking my CMAKE project with libpng in Windows

Tags: windows, cmake, libpng

I'm working on a C++ project that requires libpng. So far I've worked on Linux and everything is smooth. I installed libpng, CMAKE picks it up and everything is alright. Now move to Windows.

Here I first installed zlib (required by libpng) and libpng. When I say install, I mean I downloaded the source files, and then built them and install them using msbuild.
I noticed that by doing so, I got new folders under `c:\program files (x86)`:

```
c:\program files (x86)\zlib
c:\program files (x86)\libpng
```

Seemed all right to me. Now when I configure my project with CMAKE zlib is picked up:

```
-- Found ZLIB: C:/Program Files (x86)/zlib/lib/zlib.lib (found version "1.2.13")
```

but there's no way CMAKE finds the PNG library:

```
  Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Now I tried to have a look at the FindPNG and I noticed this line:

```
  find_path(PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR png.h PATH_SUFFIXES include/libpng)
```

Does this mean that CMAKE expects the file png.h to be in a directory ending in include/libpng? If so, then it will never find it because in my case png.h is placed in libpng/include. But this is also the "official" installation from the source code just downloaded from http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html.
So now I am superconfused. How things are supposed to work in Windows? Should I "create" a folder structure with the correct files for every library so that CMAKE is happy? In a way I hoped things in Windows were similar to what happens in Linux: libraries go in a standard folder, they are detected by CMAKE.. everything is ok. But apparently this is not the case. So my question in general is: how do you ship a package like this to a Windows user so that he can builds it without having to go through all this?

Thanks so much
Fabrizio

Comment: Please post the entire error log / output from `CMake`. Also be so kind and produce a minimal reproducible example, in this case the `CMakeLists.txt` should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

This would be the right one to use:

```
find_package(PNG)
```

You can tell CMake to look in the location where you installed it by adding the libpng base install location to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`. Without this, CMake doesn't know where you put it.

```
cmake "-DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/libpng" ...
```

Note that FindPNG first looks for zlib and will fail if zlib could not be found.